# SQL Profiler - Insert values?

Tags: sql-server-2012, profiler

I setup an SQL profiler to run, but I am not seeing any values for updates/inserts.  Is there a way to see them?

All I see is stuff like this:

```
insert into some_tbl(id, col1, col2, col3) values ( @P0 , @P1 , @P2 )
```

I would love to actually see the values being inserted rather than just a generic variable, but can't seem to figure it out?

Comment: I think it's dependant on how you query the database, aka what you're profiling. If I use RPC:Completed, then in TextData I get the query with parameters, and then the parameters specified with value afterwards.

Comment: What you're seeing is a parameterized INSERT.

Answer (score 3):

You can select `SQL:StmtStarting` and `SP:StmtStarting` along with `SQL:BatchStarting` or `SP:Starting`

[image]

Better to use server-side trace rather than using GUI.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but using the settings you posted I got the same result.  No values are given, just a bunch of P1, P2, ect

Comment: @LukeRobinson Can you post your insert statements ? Do you want the run time parameters for the variables ?

Comment: The original post is pretty much all that I am seeing on update/insert operations, I have no issues with select statements though.  I need to see the value of those variables that are being passed into insert/update statements instead of just the variable's name.

Answer (score 0):

What you ate setting there is a parametrised insert or more generically use of a "prepared statement" (you will see select statements and others like this too). You might see more specific detail in the "execute prepared SQL" trace option.

If you can't see what you need anywhere in what the profiler can show you, you could try adding a "for insert" trigger to the relevant tables to log the activity, but be very careful about efficiency with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no settings in SQL Profiler that will display the values the way you want them displayed with your `insert .. values` statement or any other similar statements.

But, by using `SP:StmtCompleted` and `SQL:StmtCompleted` you should be able to see when the values are being assigned to the parameters.

So you'll have an entry something like this for each parameter depending on how you're setting up these variables in your T-SQL code that you should see in the trace code.

```
SET @P0 = YourValue
SET @P1 = YourValue
SET @P2 = YourValue
```

If you want to filter it down to the parameters only then under Column Filters scroll down to `TextData` and add the following filters under the `LIKE` section:

```
SET @P0%
SET @P1%
SET @P2%
```

% being the wildcard.

Comment: The above method isn't the cleanest way but it definitely shows the values which is better than nothing during debugging which is a tedious process anyways!